# How to implement a two dimensional ListView

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have some data to present to the user.
The most logical way of presenting this data is a table and I really like the Material Design table:

[image: Material Design Data Table]

The number of items can vary so I'm thinking of implementing it like a  ListFragment. The problem I have is that the number of columns is also varying. 
I tried to look up some information about this, but I can't really find anything how to implement this. Should I create another ListFragment inside of the other?

I think that would make this more complex than it should be.

Comment: Is the number of Columns fixed?

Comment: I feel like GridView might be somewhere to look, It will let you choose number of columns: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee "The problem I have is that the number of columns is also varying" nope

Comment: The problem in using a GridView is that the data isn't really ordered. You set a number of columns which it should fit into. It feels kinda "hacky".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by making this from scratch.

Created a black Fragment and added a TableLayout to the XML to which I programmatic added TableRows and TextViews.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/dataTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp">
</TableLayout>
```

In the DataTable java file I used the newInstance method to create a new Fragment with the title, the headers and the data as paramters:

```
public static DataTable newInstance(ArrayList<String> headers, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data, String title) {
    DataTable fragment = new DataTable();
    fragment.setTableTitle(title);
    fragment.setHeaders(headers);
    fragment.setData(data);
    return fragment;
}
```

In the `onCreateView` method I created all the TableRows and TextViews.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data_table, container, false);

    TableLayout tableContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.dataTableLayout);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
    ll.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.getContext(),R.drawable.bottom_border));

    tableContainer.addView(ll);

    for (int headerCount = 0; headerCount < columns; headerCount++){
        TextView tvn = new TextView(this.getContext());
        tvn.setText(headers.get(headerCount));
        tvn.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

        tvn.setPadding(24,10,10,10);
        tvn.setMinWidth(200);
        tvn.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getContext(),R.color.table_header_font_color));
        tvn.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.data_table_text_size_header));
        ll.addView(tvn);
    }

    for(int rowCount = 0 ; rowCount < rows-1 ; rowCount++){
        LinearLayout lld = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());

        tableContainer.addView(lld);
        for(int columnCount = 0; columnCount < columns; columnCount++){
            TextView tvd = new TextView(this.getContext());
            tvd.setText(data.get(rowCount).get(columnCount));
            tvd.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            tvd.setPadding(24,10,10,10);
            tvd.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getContext(),R.color.table_data_font_color));
            lld.addView(tvd);
        }
        if(rowCount+2 < columns){
            lld.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.getContext(),R.drawable.bottom_border));
        }
    }
    if(tableTitle != null){
        TextView tableTitleVw = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.table_header);
        tableTitleVw.setText(tableTitle);
    }

    return view;
}
```

I wanted to do different things with the headers and the data thats why I added two for loops, I you only want to add data, one loop would suffice.

If you need to sort the table, you can use a library I found: https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView

I didn't want to be dependent on another library and I don't need all these extra functionality that's why I implemented it myself.